# Can't mount drive without using e2fsck every boot

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, drive

If i want to mount this drive, i need to run e2fsck or fsck.ext4 after every boot. All data is visible and accessable after that.

uuid only appears in system listings after "fsck.ext4" or "e2fsck". The uuid appearing after "fsck.ext4" is inside fstab and after "sudo mount -a" it mounts successfully. But next boot i have to do "fsck.ext4" or "e2fsck" and mount again.

I  remember accidentally deleting one small first partition on this disk through gparted usb. This is probably the reason for this behaviour, right? How to solve this problem?

`FV42JOA:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/wsl/hdd10                                                            mount: /mnt/wsl/hdd10: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` ( before e2fsck)

`lsblk NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT                                                               sda    8:0    0  256G  0 disk /                                                                                         sdb    8:16   0 10.9T  0 disk`

`FV42JOA:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb                                                                        e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)                                                                                             ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block                                                                           fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...                                                                  Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.                                                          Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.                                                  hdd4: recovering journal                                                                                                Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes`
...
`Pass 2: Checking directory structure                                                                                   Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity                                                                                Pass 4: Checking reference counts                                                                                      Pass 5: Checking group summary information                                                                             Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (30649, counted=1461).                                                            Fix<y>?`

...( a lot of numbers after pressing "a" at "Fix?")

`Free inodes count wrong for group #0 (21, counted=0).                                                                  Fix? yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Free inodes count wrong for group #1 (32, counted=0).                                                                  Fix? yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Free inodes count wrong for group #2 (32, counted=0).                                                                  Fix? yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Free inodes count wrong for group #3 (32, counted=7).                                                                  Fix? yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Free inodes count wrong (2861045, counted=2860935).                                                                    Fix? yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Padding at end of inode bitmap is not set. Fix? yes                                                                                                                                                                                           Block bitmap differences: Group 0 block bitmap does not match checksum.                                                FIXED.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        hdd4: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****                                                                             hdd4: 121/2861056 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 2923633429/2929721344 blocks`

`FV42JOA:~$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb                                                                  smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2] (local build)                              Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org                                                                                                                                                                   === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===                                                                                   Vendor:               WDC                                                                                              Product:              WD121KRYZ-01W0RB                                                                                 Revision:             01.0                                                                                             User Capacity:        12,000,138,625,024 bytes [12.0 TB]                                                               Logical block size:   512 bytes                                                                                        Physical block size:  4096 bytes                                                                                       LU is fully provisioned                                                                                                Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm                                                                                         Form Factor:          3.5 inches                                                                                       >> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page                                                        A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.`

`FV42JOA:~$ sudo skdump /dev/sdb                                                                          Device: sat16:/dev/sdb                                                                                                 Type: 16 Byte SCSI ATA SAT Passthru                                                                                    Size: 11444224 MiB                                                                                                     Awake: Operation not supported                                                                                         ATA SMART not supported.`

`FV42JOA:~$ sudo df                                                                                       Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used Available Use% Mounted on                                                       /dev/sda         263174212     3337580 246398476   2% /                                                                                                                                                                                    /dev/sdb       11716272064 11691920404  24335276 100% /mnt/wsl/hdd10`(after e2fsck and mount)

`FV42JOA:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb                                                                                                                                                                                              /dev/sdb:                                                                                                              SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ATA device, with non-removable media                                                                                   Standards:                                                                                                                     Likely used: 1                                                                                                 Configuration:                                                                                                                 Logical         max     current                                                                                        cylinders       0       0                                                                                              heads           0       0                                                                                              sectors/track   0       0                                                                                              --                                                                                                                     Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes                                                                      device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes                                                                     device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes                                                                     cache/buffer size  = unknown                                                                                   Capabilities:                                                                                                                  IORDY not likely                                                                                                       Cannot perform double-word IO                                                                                          R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported                                                                            DMA: not supported                                                                                                     PIO: pio0` (after e2fsck and mount)

As requested by heynnema, i want to notice that i switched to ubuntu live usb and below is not the same disk constellation as everything above, i plugged some drives in and out.

In this case (fdisk below before fsck) i have this problem with disks
/dev/sdb,
/dev/sde and
/dev/sdf

````
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.1 GiB, 2160009216 bytes, 4218768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 32.3 MiB, 33865728 bytes, 66144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: Crucial_CT120M50
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 379DAC7C-9EF1-4077-B2C6-5828602E3F12

Device         Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  39063551 39061504 18.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda2   39063552  78125055 39061504 18.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   78125056 117186559 39061504 18.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  117186560 118163455   976896  477M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  118163456 129882111 11718656  5.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  129882112 141600767 11718656  5.6G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdg: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 12.75 TiB, 14000519643136 bytes, 27344764928 sectors
Disk model: ST14000NM001G-2K
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A968E824-8EEC-4F6F-9297-E0AED5A66EEF

Device     Start   End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sde1     34 32767   32734  16M Microsoft reserved

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdf: 10.94 TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD120EMFZ-11
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CDD1B551-4A3D-4FDE-BD6D-08CC02D6875C


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 296AB478-D5B3-4E6E-8EC6-1330DD7C6AD4


Disk /dev/sdc: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2E53662E-3F2E-43B0-A5CA-3DA685BAF97C

Device      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc2  264192 15628052479 15627788288  7.3T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdh: 12.75 TiB, 14000519643136 bytes, 27344764928 sectors
Disk model: ST14000NM001G-2K
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2CX1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 12103BA4-CED8-4E6B-9B9B-DE5F407F9B77

Device      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1      34      262177      262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdd2  264192 15628052479 15627788288  7.3T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdi: 29.74 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Disk model: SD  Transcend   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7722bf23

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdi1  *     2048 62333951 62331904 29.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)```

**Thank you!**
````

Comment: You can't mount or fsck a device like /dev/sdb. You must use partitions like /dev/sdb1. You can't fsck a partition if it's mounted. If you dual-boot with Windows, and you have a Windows driver installed that will let you read/write to linux ext/2/3/4 partitions, uninstall it asap, as it'll corrupt linux file systems all the time.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. "You can't mount or fsck a device like /dev/sdb. You must use partitions like /dev/sdb1." No this is not true, i can mount it after fsck.ext4 and there is no dev/sdb1 "You can't fsck a partition if it's mounted. " yes true i never did that "if you dual-boot with Windows, and you have a Windows driver installed that will let you read/write to linux ext/2/3/4 partitions, uninstall it asap, as it'll corrupt linux file systems all the time." Ok i am not using WSL anymore, only linux... still same problem

Comment: What version Ubuntu? If you look at **most** of the commands in your question, most fail, mostly with superblock issues... that's because you specified /dev/sdb.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 2):

To properly fsck a file system, here's the correct way...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Backed up data. Reformatted the drive. Partitions are now present. It all works again.

Comment: I have 2 disks with this problem. After running fsck, one says "ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks..."Other Disk sometimes says more after that "Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data. Recovery Flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway." After that both awaits confirmation for alot of fixes. Second time fsck no errors. After reboot both disks same problem/errors as if fsck did nothing at all.

Comment: @halpplz Were you booted to a Ubuntu Live USB? Please tell me the EXACT fsck command that you used. Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: I i am on Ubuntu Live USB. I followed EXACTLY your instructions. I used "sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb". I updated question with sudo fdisk -l

Comment: @halpplz What a strange looking disk configuration. Were these disks init/format/built under WSL? I don't see partitions on most of them. I don't know WSL, so I can't explain why these disks look the way they do... but since you're apparently not using WSL any more... you may have to backup any data on sdb and reinit/reformat/rebuild sdb using standard Ubuntu procedures to get your problem fixed. Sorry I can't be of more help. Have you looked at the SMART data for sdb?

Comment: @halpplz Is halpplz a reference to the movie Fifth Element?

Comment: No, they were not created in WSL. I think the problem either was my mistake by deleting partitions on these drives or wsl really corrupted them. Now, because there seems to be no solution for my porblem, i just moved the files on another empty drive and reformatted and rebuild them so there is a 1 behind the device name e.g. sdb1.Everything working fine so far. Nevertheless thanks for your help. I did not watch this movie, should i watch it?

Comment: @halpplz Yes! Now you get what I was talking about. Partitions... like sdb1. Your drives didn't have those until you reformatted them. And yes... watch "The Fifth Element" when you can. But... watch it from beginning to end... and then tell me if it isn't one of the best choreographed movies you've ever seen... and that the acting was great... esp from Mila J. And watch for the halpplz scene.

Comment: @halpplz I updated my answer. If my answer, and our chat, was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!